# List of objects to Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

Anyone know of some code out there that does this already?  I have a bunch of pages with data grids on them in an admin website they want to export them to Excel, was hoping someone had this written already - or if not I'll post mine when I am done.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can open files in the format of CSV and XML - it can also generate the schema file.

if you have data grids then the chances are you have data sets.

There is a method on the dataset to output as XML.
you probably have to use an xmlWriter to save the file.